# listen unix /tmp/plugin155583172: bind: input/output error

Tags: linux

I am running an operation (`terraform plan` though I don't think that's important, I mention it just in case it is) inside a docker container which is failing with a fairly useless error. I have turned on detailed logging (which for terraform is done by `export TF_LOG=TRACE`)and when I do so I see the following in the trace output:

> [ERROR] plugin.terraform-provider-random_v2.3.0_x4: plugin init error: error="listen unix /tmp/plugin155583172: bind: input/output error"

I am not knowledgeable enough to know what this might mean so I'm hoping someone here has some pointers about how I can diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the root cause here but I do know how to solve it. My terraform code is in a git repo which is hosted on our gitlab instance. It was cloned to `/Users/username/git/gitlabinstancename/group/repo` and the directory from which the `terraform plan` was being run a few other directories deep.

When I cloned the repo to `/tmp` everything started working. As I said, I don't understand the root cause of the problem however I know that this fixed it so thought it was worth sharing.

Basically its an issue with the location at which I cloned the repo to and I suspect that the deep location in the directory hierarchy from where I was running the command was contributing to the problem.